# Stimulsoft report not working in MVC project

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller, stimulsoft

I've created a report using Stimulsoft in an MVC Project but after working about 24 hours I have to delete Temporary Asp.net Files from server to work again.
I've also set Enable 32-bit applications to true in iis application pool. This is the error message after working for a while:

> === Pre-bind state information ===  
>   LOG: DisplayName = System.Data.Dll (Partial)  
>   WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:  
>   WRN: Assembly Name: System.Data.Dll | Domain ID: 2  
>   WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.  
>   WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.  
>   WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,  
>   WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.  
>   WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.  
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Something  
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Something  
>   Calling assembly : Stimulsoft.Base, Version=2013.1.1505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ebe6666cba19647a.
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.  
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Somthing  
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:   
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config  
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.  
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).  
>   LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: ANd why you point your finger to Stimulsoft? How this error message relates to Stimulsoft?

Comment: All the site is working, the error is shown when report is loading.